# Remove Item from Struct (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, struct, uibutton

I have a struct

```
struct FavoriteSong {

    var title: String
    var artist: String

    init(title : String, artist : String) {
        self.title = title
        self.artist = artist
    }

    init?(dictionary : [String:String]) {
        guard let title = dictionary["title"],
            let artist = dictionary["artist"] else { return nil }
        self.init(title: title, artist: artist)
    }

    var propertyListRepresentation : [String:String] {
        return ["title" : title, "artist" : artist]
    }
}


var favoriteSongs: [FavoriteSong] = [

];
```

By pressing a `UIButton`, an object is added to the struct

```
favoriteSongs.append(FavoriteSong(title: songs[thisSong].title, artist: songs[thisSong].artist))
```

But, I want another `UIButton` that removes the object from the struct. Something like this:

```
favoriteSongs.remove(FavoriteSong(title: songs[thisSong].title, artist: songs[thisSong].artist))
```

I'm using a `UITableView` to display the information. How would I do this?

Comment: remove which element? you did not mentioned how will it work when the app scales. The example you explained it for a single struct but which element do you want to remove. Do you have a collection view or tableview of these.?? add more details !

Comment: As you are storing the favorite songs in an `Array`. So you either have to remember[store]  the `index` on which the song was stored, and then you can remove it by index. Other option is to store it in `Dictionary` by `title` and then you can remove the fvrt song by `title` key.

Comment: You could make `FavoriteSong` conform to protocol `Equatable` and then iterate through the array to find the potential index of the song using `==` operator, if found, remove it from the array.

Comment: more details, thisSong ? songs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the `index` of object and remove it, which matches your song `title` and `artist`

```
let index = favoriteSongs.index{ $0.title == songs[thisSong].title && $0.artist == songs[thisSong].artist}
if let index = index {
    favoriteSongs.remove(at: index)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct FavoriteSong : Equatable{

public static func ==(lhs: FavoriteSong, rhs: FavoriteSong) -> Bool {
    return lhs.title == rhs.title &&
            lhs.artist == rhs.artist
  }
}
```

You have to add extension to `Array` to delete object using `Equatable`

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {

// Remove first collection element that is equal to the given `object`:
mutating func remove(object: Element) {
    if let index = index(of: object) {
        remove(at: index)
    }
  }
}
```

And then you can use some thing like this

```
favoriteSongs.remove(FavoriteSong(title: songs[thisSong].title, artist: songs[thisSong].artist))
```